# When running a shell script to start nohup processes, how do I queue them to make sure they all don't run at the same time?

Tags: shell, nohup

I have a basic shell script that loops through all files in a given directory and runs them through a python program:

```
for entry in *".wav"
do
  coll=$(echo "$entry" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
  echo $name
  nohup python3 transcription.py $coll &
done
tail -f nohup.out
echo "end of batch."
```

But I want to limit this to something like 5 or 10 processes at a time. How can I go about queueing these processes so they won't start until the previous ones are finished?

Comment: Maybe use a program like GNU Parallel, it allows you to specify batch sizes and it will manage all the processes.

Comment: @Barmar Looks like it could be what I'm looking for. Thanks for the tip! I'll update if I'm able to find a solution with this.

Comment: @Barmar this ended up working perfectly. Thank you!